# Как сделать выборку?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица где постам присваивается дата создания в unix к примеру (я не буду писать в unix уж извините)

```
  id   name   create_at
   1    one   1462885556  (09.04.2016 13-00)
   2    two   1462971956  (10.05.2016 13-00)
   3    three 1462881956  (09.04.2016 12-00)
   4    four  1462968356  (10.05.2016 12-00)
   5    five  1462878356  (09.04.2016 11-00)
   6    six   1462964756  (10.05.2016 11-00)
```

надо получить так

```
10.05.2016
  2    two   (10.05.2016)
  3    four  (10.05.2016)
  6    six   (10.05.2016)
09.04.2016
  1    one   (09.04.2016)
  3    three (09.04.2016)
  5    five  (09.04.2016)
```

или php или mysql. В чем проблема- как выбрать так что бы получилось так, у  меня последний пост с датой unix соответствует 10.05.2016 13-00 то выбрать все посты от 10.05.2015 следующий день с постами  от 09.04.2016. надо сделать тоже самое.

Comment: `order by create_at desc, id asc`. Прям такой вывод из mysql вы не получите, но заготовка будет уже хорошая

Comment: @splash58 я объяснил заново в чем проблема

Comment: Какой тип поля в базе данных?

Comment: ну и получил все с последнего дня и первого  поста , А дальше? мне надо понять какой день и выбрать всё посты этого дня

Comment: акой тип поля в базе данных?

Comment: @splash58 число

Comment: в смысле прям int ? тогда `select * from thetable order by from_unixtimestamp(create_at, 'YYYYMMDD') desc, id asc`

Comment: @splash58 1305 - FUNCTION films.from_unixtimestamp does not exist

Comment: на мою память уже нельзя полагаться :) - from_unixtime

Comment: может так DATE_FORMAT?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/554346/7

Comment: Вот теперь то что надо оформляйте ответ. Большое спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильнее было бы, конечно, сделать поле create_at типа datetime. Но раз оно int, то можно использовать функцию from_unixtime таким образом:

```
select id, name, date(from_unixtime(create_at)) create_at 
    from t 
  order by create_at desc, 
           id asc
```

[демо](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/554346/7)

Answer (score 0):

если там UNIX_TIMESTAMP, то

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT FLOOR(create_at/60/60/24) as created, id, name FROM table");
$store = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$store[$row['created']] = array("id"=>$row['id'],"name"=>$row['name']);
}
```